# Config variables in package.json not working consistently

Tags: npm, package.json

I'm having issues getting `package.json` config variables to work. Take the following `package.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "tar",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "config": {
        "local_dir": "/path/to/some/directory",
        "copy_dir": "some-folder",
        "copy_exclude": "--exclude='node_modules' --exclude='.DS_Store'"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "tar:config": "cd $npm_package_config_local_dir && tar $npm_package_config_copy_exclude -pzcf example_config.tar.gz $npm_package_config_copy_dir",
        "tar:hardcoded": "cd $npm_package_config_local_dir && tar --exclude='node_modules' --exclude='.DS_Store' -pzcf example_hardcoded.tar.gz $npm_package_config_copy_dir"
    }
}
```

If I run `npm run tar:config` it does *not* exclude files and directories I've listed, but if I run `npm run tar:hardcoded` it *does* exclude these correctly. All the other configuration variables work; is there some reason the exclude list does not?

Comment: Because they're being passed as a single value, not separate arguments.

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you clarify what you mean by "single value"? If I change line 7 to `"copy_exclude": "--exclude='node_modules'"` so it's just a single entry, that still doesn't work: are you referring to something different?